# Invoke a Google Cloud Run from java

Tags: java, google-cloud-run

I want to invoke a Cloud Run from an external application. The external application is written in Kotlin (java) and run on the JDK 11 JVM. It authenticates using a service account

```
ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount).createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")
```

where the service account is is a valid JSON file. I have tested the permissions to invoke a cloud run for the service account inside the google cloud console.

I have not found an official API so I used google's GoogleNetHttpTransport to run an HTTP post request.
To invoke the cloud run I have tried to use the **HttpCredentialsAdapter**

```
transport.createRequestFactory(HttpCredentialsAdapter(googleCredentials))
   .buildPostRequest(GenericUrl(url), JsonHttpContent(JacksonFactory(), data))
```

I have tried to use the **access token** directy

```
val headers = HttpHeaders()
googleCredentials.refreshIfExpired()
headers.authorization = "Bearer " + googleCredentials.accessToken.tokenValue
postRequest.headers = headers
```

And I have tried to use a jet service account and use the **jwt request metadata**

```
val headers = HttpHeaders()
jwtCredentials = ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)
jwtCredentials.getRequestMetadata(URI(url)).forEach {
    headers.set(it.key, it.value)
}
postRequest.headers = headers
```

In all these cases it returns this error

```
[20:35:00 WARN]: Exception in thread "TestThread" com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
[20:35:00 WARN]:    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1113)
[20:35:00 WARN]:    at ***.CloudRun$invoke$3.invokeSuspend(CloudRun.kt:34)
[20:35:00 WARN]:    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[20:35:00 WARN]:    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[20:35:00 WARN]:    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

*Thanks for your support in advance*

Comment: What do you mean by "Invoke a Cloud Run"?   Cloud Run is a platform/environment for hosting REST / HTTP applications.  You create an application that listens on $PORT and responds to HTTP requests.  Do you mean invoke a custom REST application that is hosted in a container?  If yes, what is the nature of that application?

Comment: I want to post a request to another REST application that is running inside the cloud run container. The cloud run is used for various tasks and is written in node js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent time on the OAuth2 Java library and the problem is the following. The class `ServiceAccountCredentials` add an `AccessToken` as authorization, and the class `ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials` add a **self-signed** `identity token`.

I will go deeper into it, but for now you can set the header manually

```
        String myUri = "https://.....";

        Credentials credentials =  ServiceAccountCredentials
                .fromStream(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:./key.json")
                        .getInputStream()).createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");

        String token = ((IdTokenProvider)credentials).idTokenWithAudience(myUri, Collections.EMPTY_LIST).getTokenValue();

        HttpRequestFactory factory = new NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory();
        HttpRequest request = factory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(myUri));
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization","Bearer " + token);
        request.setHeaders(headers);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
        System.out.println(CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getContent(), Charsets.UTF_8)));
```

The pieces are here, but not work together.

**EDIT**

After some exchange on GitHub, a Google provide me the solution. Now the header is automatically provisioned with a signed id Token

```
        Credentials credentials =  ServiceAccountCredentials
                .fromStream(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:./key.json")
                        .getInputStream()).createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");


        IdTokenCredentials idTokenCredentials = IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
                .setIdTokenProvider((ServiceAccountCredentials)credentials)
                .setTargetAudience(myUri).build();

        HttpRequestFactory factory = new NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory(new HttpCredentialsAdapter(idTokenCredentials));
        HttpRequest request = factory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(myUri));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
        System.out.println(CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getContent(), Charsets.UTF_8)));
```

Comment: So I guess that's basically what I said but you knew Java. :)

Comment: @Gabber235 I updated my answer with the Java built in mode! No manual header required!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Java SDKs well enough, but I think I  spotted the error:

```
headers.authorization = "Bearer " + googleCredentials.accessToken.tokenValue
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should not be sending a GCP "access token" to a Cloud Run application (e.g. `https://*.run.app`). That token is for calling Google’s APIs; and Cloud Run apps are not that.

Instead, you should be sending an "identity token", which basically shows that you are in possession of the service account, without giving out any permission to the called service (to use that token to call GCP APIs).

You cannot sign an "identity token" yourself locally, you need to call an endpoint.

This is explained in this page: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-jwt

Comment: This was what I needed specifically that set me on the right track for the general problem instead of the java specific problem.