# Securely calling a Google Cloud Function via a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

How can I securely call a Google Cloud Function via a Google Apps Script?

✅ I have a Google Cloud Function, which I can access at `https://MY_REGION-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/MY_FUNCTION`, and which I would like to allow certain users to invoke via an Apps Script.

✅ To secure the Cloud Function, I have set Cloud Function Invoker to only include known email (e.g. `USER@COMPANY.com`, where this is a valid Google email).

✅ I am able to successfully invoke the Cloud Function via curl, while logged into gcloud with this email, by running: `curl https://MY_REGION-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/MY_FUNCTION -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"`.

✅ I have granted the following oauthScopes in my Apps Script's manifest:

- `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"`
- `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"`
- `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"`

⛔️ However, when I attempt to invoke the Cloud Function via a Google Apps Script, while logged in with the email `USER@COMPANY.com`, I am unable to invoke it and instead returned a 401. Here is how I have attempted to invoke the Cloud Function:

```
const token = ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();
const options = {
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
}
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://MY_REGION-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/MY_FUNCTION", options);
```

ℹ️ I have also tried the following:

- Using `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`
- Adding additional oauthScopes, e.g. `openid`.
- Creating an OAuth Client ID with `https://script.google.com` set as an Authorized Javascript origin.
- Deploying the Apps Script.
- Crying out to the sky in utter, abject despair

Comment: Do you need synchronous answer? Do you have, potentially, more than 16 call per 100 minutes?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - I do not think it is possible for an HTTP request to have a synchronous answer, nor do I need one; and no, it is not likely that this invocation will have more than 16 calls per 100 minutes.

Answer (score 27):

I struggled very much authenticating from Apps Script to invoke a Cloud Run application and just figured it out, and I believe it's similar for calling any Google Cloud application including Cloud Functions. Essentially the goal is to invoke an HTTP method protected by [Google Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam) using the authentication information you already have running Apps Script as the user.

The missing step I believe is that the technique you're using will only work if the Apps Script script and Google Cloud Function (or Run container in my case) are **in the same GCP project**. (See how to [associate the script with the GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project).)

Setting it up this way is much simpler than otherwise: when you associate the script with a GCP project, this automatically creates an [OAuth Client ID](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) configuration to the project, and Apps Script's `getIdentityToken` function returns an identity token that is only valid for that client ID (it's coded into the [`aud` field](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo) field of the token). If you wanted an identity token that works for another project, you'd need to get one another way.

If you are able to put the script and GCP function or app in the same GCP project, you'll also have to do these things, many of which you already did:

- Successfully test authentication of your cloud function via `curl https://MY_REGION-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/MY_FUNCTION -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"` (as instructed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token)). If this fails then you have a different problem than is asked in this Stack Overflow question, so I'm omitting troubleshooting steps for this.
- Ensure you are actually [who the script is running as](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts). You cannot get an identity token from custom function in a spreadsheet as they run anonymously. In other cases, the Apps Script code may be running as someone else, such as certain triggers.
- Redeploy the Cloud Function as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) (or similarly redeploy the Cloud Run container as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users)) so the app will pick up any new Client ID configuration. This is required after any new Client ID is created, including the one created automatically by adding or re-adding the script to the GCP project. (If you move the script to another GCP project and then move it back again, it seems to create another Client ID rather than reuse the old one and the old one will stop working.)
- Add the ["`openid`" scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#oauth2) (and all other needed scopes, such as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`) explicitly in the [manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes). `getIdentityToken()` will return `null` without the `openid` scope which can cause this error. Note to readers: read this bullet point carefully - the scope name is literally just "`openid`" - it's not a URL like the other scopes.

  ```
  "oauthScopes": ["openid", "https://...", ...]
  ```
- Use [`getIdentityToken()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getIdentityToken()) and do NOT use `getOAuthToken()`. According to what I've read, getOAuthToken() returns an access token rather than an identity token. Access tokens do not prove your identity; rather they just give prove authorization to access some resources.

**If you are not able to add the script to the same project as the GCP application**, I don't know what to do as I've never successfully tried it. Generally you're tasked with obtaining an OAuth identity token tied to one of your GCP client ids. I don't think one app (or GCP project) is supposed to be able to obtain an identity token for a different OAuth app (different GCP project). Anyway, it may still be possible. Google discusses OAuth authentication at a high level in their [OpenID Connect docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect). Perhaps an [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) to do a regular [Google sign-in flow](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#google_sign-in) with a [web client](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/), would work for user-present operations if you get the user to click the redirect link as Apps Script doesn't allow browser redirects. If you just need to protect your service from the public, perhaps you could try other authentication options that involve service accounts. (I haven't tried this either.) If the service just needs to know who the user is, perhaps you could parse the identity token and send the identifier of the user as part of the request. If the service needs to access their Google resources, then maybe you could have the user sign in to that app separately and use OAuth generally for long term access to their resources, using it as needed when called by Apps Script.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer.  I use a similar process to set up secure cloud functions.  The key step for me is "Redeploy the Cloud Function".  I came here today after checking all the other auth credentials, and I forgot to redeploy! (I always forget that step because it seems like the cloud function would check auth permissions at runtime - but it only checks on deployment?)

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the answer. 
I managed to get working on one Google Sheets file, but the way my project works, people will have to make a copy of the google sheets and then be able to keep making the calls to Cloud function with auth. Once I make a copy of the file, with the same user that is authorized on the original file, it does not work. I get a 401 error.
Any ideas? I've spend a lot of time on this and can make it work...
Thanks

Comment: I'm back.  Had this same problem again and found my old comment.  For copying files, you have to add the new (copied) file to the same project, then deploy the function.  It's a huge pain, but I sometimes forget one of the steps.
1) add user IAM permissions
2) add script file to the same cloud project
3) redeploy the function after 1 and 2 are done

Comment: This answer is for 1st gen functions and is still working. 2nd gen functions with the same setup 401 at this time.

Comment: It didn't work for me when I started out, but it miraculously started working on the SECOND day without any change on my part.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is very good. But since I am new with this I still had to spend a lot of time trying to figure it out.

This worked for me:

Apps Script code:

```
async function callCloudFunction() {
  const token = ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();
  const options = {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
  }
  const data = JSON.parse(await UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://MY_REGION-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/MY_FUNCTION", options).getContentText())
  return data
}
```

- Make sure that in project config you have the same project where your function is created.
- After that, you can add the emails of the users you want to access the script on the Permission section in the function.
- And as @alexander-taylor mentioned as well, make sure to add the scopes to your manifest file. You can make the manifest visible from the configuration tab in apps script. It took me some time to get that too.

Comment: Stack overflow does not let edits right now (too many edits pending), but the `await` in the code is completely unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your comment you can do 2 things. But before, you have to know that you can't (or I least I never achieve this), create a valid identity token for being authenticated by Cloud Function and Cloud Run with a user credential. [I opened a question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754530/use-user-account-credential-for-reaching-private-cloud-run-cloud-functions)

But you can call Google Cloud API with user credential! So

- You can use [the function test call API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/call). The quotas limit you to 16 calls per 100 minutes (of course, it's design for test!)
- You can publish a message into [PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) and [plug your function on it](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub). In this pattern your call is asynchronous.