# How to trigger a Google Cloud Function using a Google Sheets Trigger?

Tags: http, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, triggers

I am trying to trigger a Google cloud function using an HTTP request from a Google Apps Script connected to Google Sheets.

The cloud function (tested with a dummy request on GCP, this works) essentially gets the latest entry of the sheet as submitted by users using the [Appsheet](https://www.appsheet.com/) front-end. I would like it to be triggered whenever a new submission occurs. As such, I am using a `onChange(e)` trigger to send the request. This is the code I have so far in the appscript.

```
function onChange(e) {
  Logger.log('called');
  var url = "https://MY_REGION-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION";
  const token = ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();
  const options = {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
  }
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log('Response Code: ' + response.getResponseCode());
}
```

The stackdriver logs give me the following error when a new Appsheet submission is made (thus calling `onChange(e)`):

```
Exception: Request failed for https://MY_REGION-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net returned code 401. Truncated server response: 
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
    at onChange(Code:9:32)
```

I have looked at and followed the solutions and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021266/triggering-a-cloud-function-from-google-sheets-via-google-apps-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781421/securely-calling-a-google-cloud-function-via-a-google-apps-script), but they didn't help me much; that is, I have made sure that the app script is connected to my project, re-deployed the cloud function, and added `openid` to the scope to the manifest.

Given that it is still not working, I would like some guidance on this. Am I still missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a temporary fix; hard code the authentication token into the App Script. The authentication token is given by running `gcloud auth print-identity-token` in the Google Cloud Shell script. Copy the output and replace the corresponding line in `onChange(e)` method.

```
function onChange(e) {
  Logger.log('called');
  var url = "https://MY_REGION-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION";
  const token = ScriptApp.getIdentityToken(); //<-- Replace this line!
  const options = {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
  }
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log('Response Code: ' + response.getResponseCode());
}
```

There seems to be a bug in the API which doesn't get value of the token when the `ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()` is called. I've brought this up in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). Hopefully, it is fixed soon.

Note that hardcoding the authentication token may only be a temporary solution as that token can change. Be sure to regularly update it in the App Script if you want to continue to use this method.

Answer (score 2):

Pivoted from Bhairav's answer, we don't have to manually copy and paste the identity token. Here is how we can call the **getIdentityToken()** function

- Associate the appscript project with a standard GCP project
  (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)
- Update the manifest.json to include the following scope:

  "oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
  ],

You should be able to call **ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();** without any problem

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

#### GAS Triggers Don't Listen for Programmatic Changes

Neither `onChange`, nor `onEdit` triggers are invoked by programmatic access to the Sheet. ([Reference](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/diference-between-onedit-or-onchange-trigger)). I've tried to build stuff like this in the past, and been thwarted.

#### How I've Handled This

I've handled this by creating a dedicated tab where other apps, which have write access to the sheet, programmatically add stringified objects to a cell. Then, I have a GAS function that, each minute, looks for new activities (the stringified objects), then does stuff based on what's inside the parsed activity object. To use this approach, you'll need to:

- build the "activities handling" function into your Script
- set up a time-based trigger (I do it once a minute) to look for those activities, then handle them

It's not a perfect solution, but it works well for me.